# SQL Injection vulnerability on Searchable Android AppTv

Tags: android-tv, android-security

I made my TV app searchable but Google told me that the app has an SQL Injection vulnerability and directed me to this guide to fix it (https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7668308).

However, by selecting "exported = false" my app no longer appears in the TV search.

I also tried to follow the example app provided by google (https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) in which is used

```
exported = true
<path-permission
            android:pathPrefix="/search"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
```

But the vulnerability persists.

This is my Provider declaration into manifest

```
<provider
        android:name=".xxx.xxx.contentProvider.DiretteProvider"
        android:authorities="${packageName}"
        android:exported="false">
        <path-permission
            android:pathPrefix="/search"
            android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
    </provider>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692596/android-security-google-play-warning-your-app-contains-a-sql-injection-issue)?

Comment: Yes, but it did not help me